# No gradients provided for any variable error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm creating a model using the Keras functional API.

The layer architecture is as follows:

```
n = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(input)

for i in tf.range(n):
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4)(input)
```

I then concat the outputs and return for a tensor with shape [1, None, 4] where [1] is the batch dimension, [None] is n, and [4] is the output from the second dense layer.

My loss function involves comparing the shape of the expected output, and comparing the outputs.

```
loss = tf.convert_to_tensor(abs(tf.shape(logits)[1] - tf.shape(expected)[1])) * 100.
```

When running this on a custom training loop, I'm getting the error

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['while/dense/kernel:0', 
'while/dense/bias:0', 'while/while/dense_1/kernel:0', 'while/while/dense_1/bias:0'],).
Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, <tf.Variable 'while/dense/kernel:0' shape=(786432, 1)
```

Comment: Your layers are disconnected, the output of the first dense layer is not a part of the input of the second layer! Repeating the second layer ( n ) times doesn't mean the backpropagation ( = gradients )can propagate from the second layer to the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shape is not differentiable, you cannot do things like this with gradient based learning. Problems like this need to be tackled with more powerful tools, e.g. reinforcement learning where one considers n as an action, and get policy gradient for that.

A rule of thumb to remember is that you cannot really backprop through **discrete** objects. You need to produce floats, as gradients require **smooth** functions. In your case n should be an integer (what does a loop over a float mean?) so this should be your first warning sign. The other being shape itself, which is also an integer. A **target** can be discrete, but not the prediction. Note that even in classification we do not output **class** we output **probability** as probability is smooth.

You could build your model by assuming some maximum number of N and treat it more like a classification where you supervise N directly, and use some form of masking to keep all the results around.

Comment: Yes, N is an integer. I take the float, scale it between 0 and 1, and then take 1 / N, and cast to an int. I thought that Keras would update the first dense layer that produces N, as it directly causes the shape to be different. Is that not how it works?

Comment: no, as soon as you make it into integer gradients are no longer defined

Comment: OK. So what I see as a possible solution: train the first dense layer individually, with the output of the activation equal to the float (ie. 0.33333 instead of 3, as 1/0.33333 = ~3). Then keep the dense layer in this model non-trainable, but copy the weights from the layer that was being trained before between epochs.

Comment: I think you also missed that you cannot use abs as a function in a loss, you have to use tf.abs instead (to allow for autodiff).